# Getting Specific Results in Output

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Hey guys hopefully you can help me got 2 quick questions dealing with sql.

Lets say I have a table:

```
  Sports:
  Soccer
  Basketball
  Nothing
```

Now a group of 10 ppl can choose what sport they like! And is recorded already in the table then using the command:

```
SELECT count(sports)
FROM peoplewhovotedinsports s
GROUP BY sports
```

Will give me a tally in order of how many people joined each sport 
ex:

5(soccer)

4(basketball)

1(nothing)

Now soccer should be the one that shows up but, what would I type in order for it to only give me the soccer to how/the highest sport choosen ?

For ex:
QUESTIONS HAVE BEEN SOLVED TY !!

Which just lists the persons name and what they are subbed to but individual lines like:
       JOEY Sports
       JOEY Tech
       Tom Sports

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: done. Sorry for the confusion the main questions reworded and in bold

Comment: theres a invalid table **facilities** in the schema !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated

Could you try this?

```
SELECT p.name, m.mags
FROM people p, peoplewhosub ms, magazines m 
WHERE p.portid = ms.line and ms.service = m.scode 
  AND p.portid IN (
    SELECT line
    FROM peoplewhosub 
    GROUP BY line
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Comment: so i tried that as well but it wont work due to the line 
WHERE portid = ms.line and ms.service = m.scode 

it makes it so that 
the output is like:
Joey Sports
Joey Tech
so each one is count of 1 instead of 2, I think i have to mod the WHERE line so it put the sports and tech on the same line. So when i do the count it thinks everything is one so it puts nothing

Comment: yes this is perfect ty!!, now i just gotta find someone to help me with #1

Comment: @user3044157 I have modified to make query faster. could you try it? and can be compared each other? if so, Let me know which is faster.

Comment: it makes it out of order in terms of the name, but it does seem to be quicker...any way to mod it so its just one name instead of it showing multple of the same name ?

Comment: @user3044157 If everything is fine but display order is disordered. I think, adding "ORDER BY p.name;" end of query might help you.

Comment: What if I wanted only 1 of the same name to appear ?

Comment: @user3044157 ah~ your requirement is changed. then `SELECT DISTINCT p.name` this might help you! It's time to work for me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING()` for those who subscribed more than one magazine:

```
SELECT p.name, COUNT(*) as NumberOfSubscription
FROM peoplewhosub ws
INNER JOIN people p
ON ws.line = p.portid
GROUP BY p.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

On the first one you could use `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT sports, count(*) as TopSports
FROM peoplewhovotedinsports
GROUP BY sports
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Ty the you helped with the first part !